# Django authentication works on a page, but not another

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication

I've been working on Django Authentication, but I have stumbled on a problem: login works on a page (the "post detail" page of the blog), but not on the homepage.

This is the part of the `base.html` that handles this header

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <a href="{% url 'blog.views.post_new' %}" class="top-menu header-icon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
    <a href="{% url 'blog.views.post_draft_list' %}" class="top-menu header-icon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a>
    <p class="top-menu">Hello, <a href="/edit/">{{ user.first_name }}</a>!<small> (<a href="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout' %}">Log out</a>)</small></p>
{% else %}
<form>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if next %}
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
    {% endif %}

    {{ login_form.as_p }}
</form>
{% endif %}
```

The **view** seems good to me, anyway here it is

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        login_form = CustomLoginForm(request.POST)

        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password1')

        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                auth_login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Your Blog account is disabled.")
        else:
            print "Invalid login details: {0}, {1}".format(email, password)
            return HttpResponse("Invalid login details supplied. Get back to the <a href=\"/\">homepage</a>.")
    else:
        login_form = CustomLoginForm()

    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {})

def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-published_date')
    user = CustomUser.objects.all()

    user_form = CustomUserCreationForm()
    login_form = CustomLoginForm()

    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts, 'user_form': user_form, 'login_form': login_form, 'user': user})
```

I think the core of the problem could be on either the header of the base.html file or on the view.

This is what I see on the homepage (even when I'm logged in)

[image]

This is what I see on the post-detail page (and that's what I should see on the homepage too)

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: Where does it not work? What is 'homepage'? What does your views look like?

Comment: Added info on the question.

Comment: I've edited out pretty much all of the code you've included since the majority wasn't relevant to the actual question you're asking, you should aim to create a [mcve] of your problem

Comment: Do you have ` 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth'` in the proper context processor place in your `settings.py` file? In Django <= 1.8, this would be the `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting. in Django 1.9+, this should be in the `context_processors` portion of the `OPTIONS` dictionary in the `TEMPLATES` setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
user = CustomUser.objects.all()
```

and then

```
return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', 
              {'posts': posts, 'user_form': user_form, 
               'login_form': login_form, 'user': user})
```

You are passing a queryset result consisting of `CustomUser` objects as `user` in your request context. It overwrites the `user` variable assigned by the `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` context processor.

To solve the problem, simply change the name of the template variable to something else, such as:

```
return render(...
              'users': user})
```